# How can I create context menu shortcut for famous file extension like JPG

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu, right-click

I read that if I need to add item to the context menu for specific files type, I should do the following :

in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT at Regedit go to the file type you want to modify ((ex:.jpg)) and add "Shell" key if not exists, then create inside the "Shell" key the command you need and inside it create "command" key then in the default value for the "command" key set the application or the command that you want..

This worked perfectly for me for the "non famous" extensions, but when I tried to do that for the ".JPG" file type it didn't worked!

And above all, when I removed the whole ".jpg" key it kept working fine like nothing happened.

My question, should I do something special when I work with this file type or something like this...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about the .JPG extension; it's like any other. Instead of manually editing the registry, you can use [**FileTypesMan**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) for this:

> FileTypesMan is an alternative to the 'File Types' tab in the 'Folder Options' of Windows. It displays the list of all file extensions and types registered on your computer. For each file type, the following information is displayed: Type Name, Description, MIME Type, Perceived Type, Flags, Browser Flags, and more.
>
> FileTypesMan also allows you to easily edit the properties and flags of each file type, as well as it allows you to add, edit, and remove actions in a file type.

[image: 1]